# Make form_tag behave more like form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I need form_tag to return parameters in the same format that form_for returns them in.

form_for return the params something like this:

```
{"person"=>{"name"=>"bob", "age"=>"30", "etc"=>"bla"}}>
```

form_tag will do the following:

```
{"name"=>"bob", "age"=>"30", "etc"=>"bla"}
```

How can I get form_tag to return parameters the same way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your fields.
Maybe instead of:

```
<%= text_field_tag "name", "" %>
<%= text_field_tag "age", "" %>
<%= text_field_tag "etc", "" %>
```

You put something like this:

```
<%= text_field_tag "person[name]", "" %>
<%= text_field_tag "person[age]", "" %>
<%= text_field_tag "person[etc]", "" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => "persons", :action => "index", :p => params.except(:controller, :action)) %>
```

or

```
<%= form_tag( params.merge( :controller => "persons", :action => "index" )) %>
```